# Count values if text contains in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a datasource that looks like this:

| combinations |
| --- |
| A |
| A |
| A,B |
| B |
| A,C |
| A,B,C |

what I want to do is to create a table that count every single time one combination occurs OR is contained in another combination. For that there are two steps:

1. output all the unique combinations.
2. Count every single time that combination occurs or is contained in another combination.

In this example, the desired output is this one:

| combinations | frequency |
| --- | --- |
| A | 5 |
| B | 3 |
| A,B | 2 |
| A,C | 2 |
| A,B,C | 1 |

Any ideas on how I can achieve this with BigQuery or SQL? I have tried with Count(), but the results are not correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the unique combinations then use `join` to count:

```
select c.combination, count(*)
from (select distinct combination from t) c join
     t
     on concat(',', t.combination, ',') like concat('%,', c, ',%')
group by c.combination;
```

EDIT:

The above treats combinations as strings.  If you want to treat the combinations as individual values, then storing them in strings is the wrong data structure.  However, you can still do what you want by using arrays:

```
select t.combination, countif(num_combos = num_matches)
from (select t.combination, t.num_combos, t2.seqnum, count(*) as num_matches       ​
      from (select distinct t.combination,
                   ​​split(t.combination, ',') as ar_combos,
                   ​​array_length(split(t.combination, ',')) as num_combos
            ​​​from t
           ​​​) t cross join
           ​​unnest(t.ar_combos) ar join
           ​​(select t2.*, row_number() over (order by combination) as seqnum,
                   ​ar2
            ​from t t2 cross join
                 ​​unnest(split(t2.combination, ',')) ar2
           ​​) t2
           ​​on t2.ar2 = ar
     group by t.combination, t.num_combos, t2.seqnum
    ) t
group by combination;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach

```
select a.combination, countif((
    select count(1) = array_length(split(a.combination))
    from unnest(split(a.combination)) item
    join unnest(split(d.combination)) item
    using(item)
  )) frequency
from (select distinct combination from data) a, data d
group by a.combination
# order by array_length(split(a.combination)), a.combination
```

if applied to sample data in your question

[image]

output is

[image]